# OnItemClickListener causing exception in my listview

Tags: android, android-intent, onitemclicklistener

my problem is really simple but i cannot seem to figure out where i am going wrong with the code or whether i'm implementing it right.
I am loading my listview using volley.On clicking the item so as to go to the Details activity,the activity stops.I have registered the Details activity in the manifest and i'll  upload my logcat too so if you see where i might have gone wrong,please help me figure it out.Thanks.

FrontPage.java:

```js
    public class Frontpage extends ActionBarActivity{
 private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
 private static String Title="title";
 private static String Desc="desc";
 private static String Date ="pubDate";
 
 private ListView lstView;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ArrayList<NewsModel> arrNews ;
    private LayoutInflater lf;
    private VolleyAdapter va;
    private ProgressBar pDialog;

    @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.trending);
        
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

   Intent newActivity4=new Intent();
   setResult(RESULT_OK, newActivity4);
        
        
    lf = LayoutInflater.from(this);


   arrNews = new ArrayList<NewsModel>();
    va = new VolleyAdapter();

    lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lstView.setAdapter(va);
    mRequestQueue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://snapt.t15.org/news.js";
    pDialog =(ProgressBar)this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
  pDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    try{
           
   }catch(Exception e)
   {

   }
   JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest
  (Request.Method.GET,url,null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
   @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
     Log.i(TAG,response.toString());
     parseJSON(response);
     va.notifyDataSetChanged();
     pDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
;            }
   },new Response.ErrorListener() {
   @Override
   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    if (error instanceof NoConnectionError){
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Bummer..There's No Internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }};
 });
 mRequestQueue.add(jr);

 }
    
    
 private void parseJSON(JSONObject json){
   try{
    JSONObject value = json.getJSONObject("value");
    JSONArray items = value.getJSONArray("items");
    for(int i=0;i<items.length();i++){

 JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);
    NewsModel nm = new NewsModel();
   nm.setTitle(item.optString("title"));
   nm.setDescription(item.optString("description"));
   nm.setLink(item.optString("link"));
   nm.setPubDate(item.optString("pubDate"));
    arrNews.add(nm);
 }}

catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
  }

    
 lstView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){ 

 @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) { 
  String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title))
 .getText().toString();
    String desc = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description))
 .getText().toString();
      
   Intent i = new Intent(Frontpage.this, Detail.class);
   i.putExtra(Title, name);
   i.putExtra(Desc, desc);
      
   startActivity(i);
  }
 });}
 class NewsModel{
 private String title;
  private String link;
  private String description;
   private String pubDate;

  void setTitle(String title) {
 this.title = title;
  }

  void setLink(String link) {
 this.link = link;
  }

 void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
  this.pubDate = pubDate;
  }

 String getLink() {
    return link;
        }

 String getDescription() {
   return description;
        }

  String getPubDate() {
  return pubDate;
  }

  String getTitle() {

return title;
        }
    }


 class VolleyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

@Override
  public int getCount() {
   return arrNews.size();
    }
 @Override
   public Object getItem(int i) {
    return arrNews.get(i);
 }

@Override
  public long getItemId(int i) {
      return 0;
        }

 @Override
   public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
   ViewHolder vh ;
   if(view == null){
  vh = new ViewHolder();
   view = lf.inflate(R.layout.row_listview,null);
   vh.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    vh.tvDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
   vh.tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
   view.setTag(vh);
   }
else{
   vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
   }

  NewsModel nm = arrNews.get(i);
  vh.tvTitle.setText(nm.getTitle());
  vh.tvDesc.setText(nm.getDescription());
   vh.tvDate.setText(nm.getPubDate());
  return view;
  }

  class  ViewHolder{
    TextView tvTitle
    TextView tvDesc;
    TextView tvDate;

 }
 }
}
```

DetailsActivity.java:

```
public class NewsDetails extends ActionBarActivity{
private static String Title="title";
private static String Desc="desc";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.newsdetail);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
Intent i=getIntent();
String name = i.getStringExtra(Title);
String desc = i.getStringExtra(Desc);

TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
lblName.setText(name);
lblDesc.setText(desc);
}}
```

logcat:

```
01-09 15:42:04.031: E/dalvikvm(19341): GC_CONCURRENT freed 437K, 30% free 9679K/13763K, paused 4ms+17ms, total 73ms
01-09 15:42:04.161: I/Frontpage(19341): {"value":{"callback":"","generator":"http:\/\/pipes.yahooapis.com\/pipes\/","pubDate":"Fri, 09 Jan 2015 10:15:08 +0000","title":"Cycling News","items":[{"guid":{"content":"urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,lego:19780928:top,article,fe3b6341-a4cf-3812-84e7-bf05a6fcc813-l:1","isPermaLink":"false"},"pubDate":"Thu, 08 Jan 2015 04:47:55 PST","category":"SC","title":"ROOM BOOKING TO BEGIN ON WEDNESDAY 7TH","y:title":"Former Tour winner Wiggins launches his own cycling team (The Associated Press)","y:id":{"value":"urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,lego:19780928:top,article,fe3b6341-a4cf-3812-84e7-bf05a6fcc813-l:1","permalink":"false"},"description":"Hostel booking by Incoming Students has been rescheduled to WEDNESDAY 7TH JANUARY 2015 as from 2.30pm.This is a change from the prior Information indicated; with the Dates of 4th ? 6th (the same time that re-booking by continuing students was to be between 24th Dec ? 4th January 2015).As explained by the ICT Officer (In charge of the Hostels Management System), Mr. Masibo, the changes, are as a result of the following:\n? Slow Rate of Re-booking by the Continuing Students (Majorly the 1st years). Some of whom had forgotten their passwords and needed their accounts to be rest.\n? By Yesterday?s deadline, less than half of such students had Rebooked (retained) their rooms thus posing a challenge in opening the system for the incoming groups. Thus between now, they are urged to hasten their process of re-booking. ","link":"http:\/\/us.rd.yahoo.com\/sports\/rss\/sc\/SIG=139h7572n\/*http%3A\/\/sports.yahoo.com\/news\/former-tour-winner-wiggins-launches-own-cycling-team-124755795--spt.html","y:published":{"minute":"47","day_of_week":"4","utime":"1420721275","timezone":"UTC","day_name":"Thursday","second":"55","day_ordinal_suffix":"th","month":"1","year":"2015","month_name":"January","day":"8","hour":"12"},"y:repeatcount":"1"},{"guid":{"content":"urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,lego:19780928:top,article,c9aeb898-8485-36f9-8171-08179126c1cd-l:1","isPermaLink":"false"},"pubDate":"Thu, 08 Jan 2015 04:07:47 PST","media:content":{"type":"image\/jpeg","url":"http:\/\/l.yimg.com\/iu\/api\/res\/1.2\/yeyi9ZW1Brm77oKQ5YwDkw--\/YXBwaWQ9eXZpZGVvO2NoPTI4Njtjcj0xO2N3PTI4NjtkeD04MztkeT0xO2ZpPXVsY3JvcDtoPTEzMDtxPTEwMDt3PTEzMA--\/http:\/\/media.zenfs.com\/en_us\/News\/Reuters\/2015-01-08T120747Z_1_LYNXMPEB070GQ_RTROPTP_2_SPORT-GAMES.JPG","width":"130","height":"130"},"category":"SC","title":"Former Tour champion Wiggins to launch own team (Reuters)","y:title":"Former Tour champion Wiggins to launch own team (Reuters)","y:id":{"value":"urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,lego:19780928:top,article,c9aeb898-8485-36f9-8171-08179126c1cd-l:1","permalink":"false"},"description":"<p><a rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"http:\/\/us.rd.yahoo.com\/sports\/rss\/sc\/SIG=1317e54jm\/*http%3A\/\/sports.yahoo.com\/news\/former-tour-champion-wiggins-launch-own-team-120747028--spt.html\"><img src=\"http:\/\/l.yimg.com\/iu\/api\/res\/1.2\/yeyi9ZW1Brm77oKQ5YwDkw--\/YXBwaWQ9eXZpZGVvO2NoPTI4Njtjcj0xO2N3PTI4NjtkeD04MztkeT0xO2ZpPXVsY3JvcDtoPTEzMDtxPTEwMDt3PTEzMA--\/http:\/\/media.zenfs.com\/en_us\/News\/Reuters\/2015-01-08T120747Z_1_LYNXMPEB070GQ_RTROPTP_2_SPORT-GAMES.JPG\" width=\"130\" height=\"130\" alt=\"England's Bradley Wiggins (R) leads his team to a silver medal in men's 4000m team pursuit finals at the 2014 Commonwealth Games in Glasgow, Scotland, July 24, 2014.          REUTERS\/Phil Noble\" align=\"left\" border=\"0\"><\/a><\/p><p>LONDON (Reuters) - Four-times Olympic champion and former Tour de France winner Bradley Wiggins is launching his own professional cycling team with the aim of providing more British gold in Rio. Wiggins, who will continue to ride for Team Sky until April's Paris Roubaix road classic before concentrating on his own Rio 2016 Olympic preparations, will head up the team comprising of young home-grown riders. The team, which will operate independently of British Cycling and focus on both road and track disciplines, will be called WIGGINS and will receive financial backing from Sky. ...<\/p><br
01-09 15:42:09.011: W/dalvikvm(19341): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dfa438)
01-09 15:42:11.501: E/Trace(23337): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-09 15:42:11.541: W/dalvikvm(23337): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
01-09 15:42:11.661: W/System.err(23337): Invalid int: ""
01-09 15:42:12.101: I/Adreno200-EGL(23337): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
01-09 15:42:12.101: I/Adreno200-EGL(23337): Build Date: 10/26/12 Fri
01-09 15:42:12.101: I/Adreno200-EGL(23337): Local Branch: 
01-09 15:42:12.101: I/Adreno200-EGL(23337): Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
01-09 15:42:12.101: I/Adreno200-EGL(23337): Local Patches: NONE
01-09 15:42:12.101: I/Adreno200-EGL(23337): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010 +  NOTHING

If you need more code,please ask.
```

Comment: You didn't post the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `R.id.txtTitle` and `R.id.txtDesc` for getting TextView value from row because row layout contain TextView's with `R.id.txtTitle` and `R.id.txtDesc` id's instead of `R.id.title` and `R.id.description`.

```
  String name = (String)((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText();
  String desc =(String)((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc)).getText();
```

Comment: Thanks that has worked :)i really  appreciate your help